# Detect scrolling on top of webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to dedect if the user scrolls to the top of a webpage when he is already on the top. This means that normal scrolling shouldn't trigger a action, just if the scrollbar is on the top and the user scrolls further to the top it does something.

I have tried with the code below, but it triggers when the user arrives on top and not when he "overscroll" it. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fqyhkd30/) is the jsfiddle.

```js
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) ==window.innerHeight) {
        alert("The action");
    }
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML= window.scrollY+";"+window.innerHeight+";"+(window.innerHeight+ + window.scrollY);
};
```

```css
p{
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<p id="a">sdf
</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: What does it not do now? Also use console.log instead of alert to not interrupt the scrolling

Comment: When the user is on the top and scrolls up it doesn't triggers

Comment: And if you test || scrollY==0 ?

Comment: the problem is that the onscroll won't be triggered if you scroll up when you ar already on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's acceptable to ignore the top line of pixels in the window then you can set the scroll position at one pixel down. Then if the user scrolls up into this zone then good things happen.

You could try something like this fiddle:

```js
var scrolling = false, w = $(window);
w.scrollTop(1);

w.on({
 scroll: function() {
   if(w.scrollTop() === 0){ // are we in the 'zero bufferzone'?
     $('#monitor').text('overscrolling');
   }
        
    clearTimeout(scrolling); // reset timer
    scrolling = setTimeout(function() {
        if(w.scrollTop() === 0){
           w.scrollTop(1); // shift down by a pixel
           $('#monitor').text(''); // reset
        }
    }, 250);
    }
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 3000px;
}

#monitor{
  position: fixed;
  left: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='monitor'></div>
```